# Stop Google push notification, response "channel not found for project"

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar Push Notifications. All is working well and I register my channel with no issue. Changes to the calendar result in a notification as expected.

I want to stop the push notification. I am calling Google stop push notification API. 
"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/channels/stop"
But I am getting Error code: `404 and message: "Channel not found for project"`.

Request:

```
googleCalendar.channels.stop({
       auth: oauth2Client,
        resource: {
            id: 'cfabcfaa-a6eb-4432-8068-6417ee2ce8a6', //channelID
            resourceId: '3kGwQdmzSMCZ41MAFdwEzt0ugNQ'   //resourceID
        } 
      }, function(err, results) {
         if(err){
         return;
         }
         console.log(results) })
```

Response:

```
{ [Error: Channel 'cfabcfaa-a6eb-4432-8068-6417ee2ce8a6' not found for project '87165627894']
  code: 404,
  errors:
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'notFound',
       message: 'Channel \'cfabcfaa-a6eb-4432-8068-6417ee2ce8a6\' not found for project \'87165627894\'' } ] }
```

Can anyone help me why I am getting this error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't confirm if you're using a library, but it seems that you're calling the [calendarList watch](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/watch) method and not the [channel stop](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/channels/stop) method (which is used to stop push notification).

Based on the [Push Notification](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push?hl=en#stopping-notifications) page in the Calendar API documentation, the required fields are indeed channelID and resourceID (as what you've specified; also required is the auth token of the user)

`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/channels/stop`

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/channels/stop
Authorization: Bearer {auth_token_for_current_user}
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "4ba78bf0-6a47-11e2-bcfd-0800200c9a66",
  "resourceId": "ret08u3rv24htgh289g"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer '@adjuremods'. I am sorry  I did some mistake. I have updated my question. I am passing auth label which has auth token, I have been working on this issue from 3 days, still getting same error message. actually I have called 'watch list event' API too many times, not able to stop any watch. you are right, I am using node 'googleapis' library. please assist me if it's working in your case.

Comment: Hi '@adjuremods', it's working. I was testing from local server, I should have understand from error message. It says 'Channel not found for project', its means channel is not able to my project id. Google created different- different id for my local server and my live server. I am happy my code is working now. Thank you for your help too...

Comment: @AnuragChoudhary, can you explain what do you mean by different ids. I encounter similar issues. your help would be appreciated

Comment: @PankajShrestha, when i was testing (I accidentally created lots of channel  ) from localhost. And I was calling the API with last channel Id And that Id was not correct for production. I created two projects on google one for local and one for production. Your must stop the channel from that project you used to create that channel.