# Google Reports API channels.stop returns 404 Error

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk, google-api-python-client

When using google-api-python-client to stop receiving push notifications, it returns Error 404: Channel not found

I call the method as follows:

```
body = {
           'id': "0ddjjjdkd-b29b-asdb-9493-d698abcdkj",
           'resourceId': "33sansej8i-hT3Tj0abcdFybQKiU"
       }
reports_service.channels().stop(body=body).execute()
```

The response received is as follows:

> HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/admin/reports_v1/channels/stop?
>   returned "Not Found">

A previous SO post ([Stop watching google push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327874/stop-watching-google-push-notifications)) explained that the URL was incorrect. However, on trying the recommended URL in Oauth playground, I get the same result. 
Moreover, I get a result message:
    "Channel 'f276e057-b177-41be-b7ds6-392nnn32' not found for project '407408718192'"
I have no project with this ID.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you testing it from a local server?

Comment: Yes. It is a local server

Comment: Check this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618420/stop-google-push-notification-response-channel-not-found-for-project).